# Programmatically multiselect rows in WinForms DatagridView properly

Tags: .net, winforms, datagrid

Is it possible and if so, how, to programmatically select non-consecutive rows in a standard WinForms datagrid?

```
foreach (var selectableRowIndex in selectableRowIndices)
{
    dataGridView.Rows[selectableRowIndex ].Selected = true;
}
```

...  does work, but after setting the dataGridView's .CurrentCell Property via

```
dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView.Rows[underlyingRowIndex].Cells[1];
```

all other rows get deselected.

What's the proper way to set the current row/cell and keep other rows selected?

Comment: since you are talking about a `Rows` property, i assume you are using the `DataGridView` instead of the `DataGrid` class.

The code you are using works fine here... can you confirm that the `MultiSelect` property of your `DataGridView` is set to `true`?

Comment: Multiselect is set to true indeed and yes it is a DataGridView, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick and dirty solution would be:

-get the IDs of the currently selected rows
-change the current cell
-re-select the rows

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and my solution was to have a `List<Int32>` with the ids of the selected rows and to add or remove the ids as needed.